# Convert JSON data into a downloadable Excel

Tags: javascript, json, excel, filesaver.js

I'm trying to convert JSON data into a downloadable Excel file in my JavaScript code. I tried to [use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2xls) but can't get it to work. From the documentation, I'm copying the same exact code as given below:

```
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var json = {
    foo: 'bar',
    qux: 'moo',
    poo: 123,
    stux: new Date()
}

var xls = json2xls(json);

fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: fs.writeFileSync is not a function
```

I also tried looking into FileSaver.js [here](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) but it only seems to work for text blobs.

Is there an alternative to download Excel files?

Comment: is this node.js or a browser? json2xsl is for node, filesaver.js is for browsers...

Answer (score 0):

try putting

`var fs = require("fs");` at the top of your code, if its not already

EDIT

I tried your code out, and got it to work. I suspect your version of node does not have the fs.writeFileSync() function defined. Try using the non-sync writeFile, like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var json = {
    foo: 'bar',
    qux: 'moo',
    poo: 123,
    stux: new Date()
}

var xls = json2xls(json);

console.log(fs);

// THIS WORKED FOR ME
//fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary');

// TRY THIS , MAYBE YOU HAVE AN OLD VERSION OF NODE THAT DOES NOT HAVE fs.writeFileSync
fs.writeFile('data2.xlsx', xls, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('saved file');
});
```